# How can I make a list of factions, each of which has a "reputation" according to every other faction?

Tags: unity, c#, ai

In my game, I'd like each and every NPC to belong to a faction, such as Bandits, Townsfolk, Elves, etc.. Each faction would then have an opinion of each other faction, stored as an integer rating, and if an NPC of one faction meets a member of an enemy faction, they'll attack.

How can I keep track of these factions and the relationships between them? I've tried creating a list of factions in a `FactionManager`, but then I don't know how to manage relationships.

Here is a similar query but for Python: [How should I efficiently store faction relationships?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/how-should-i-efficiently-store-faction-relationships)

Comment: What have you tried in regards of converting the Python solution into C#? Is the issue just converting the solution in the linked answer into C#? Where are you running into issues?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I don't know any python ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  I don't understand the solution.

Comment: Is the general description of the solution not enough? "You could keep the factions in a dictionary inside your scenario/map/level instance, using ("groupA", "groupB") tuples as keys to store the relations between groups." I don't think questions that just require translating a solution from language A to language B is a good fit to this site, as a game developer won't give a better answer to that compared to any programmer.

Comment: The 2d array solution is also a general solution that could be implemented in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2D array (matrix), and store accordingly. The left column here is the primary column, i.e. townsfolk's opinion of elves (elves' rep with townsfolk) is 0.5. Whereas elves opinion of townsfolk is less flattering (0.3).

|  | townsfolk | bandits | elves |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| townsfolk | 1.0 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| bandits | 0.8 | 1.0 | 0.6 |
| elves | 0.4 | 0.2 | 1.0 |

Why have I used a floating point value between 0.0 and 1.0, instead of an integer? `float` is flexible:

- Any maximum number we pick, such as 100 or 5000, would anyway be a contrived figure, which we could arrive at just by mutiplying by some constant `k`. (e.g. 0.3 * 5000 = 1500). So `0.0-1.0` is "solution agnostic" if we change `k`.
- Floating point isn't restricted to "stepped" values such as all integers between 1 and 100. It is an *analog* range.

In C#:

```
enum Factions
{
    Townsfolk,
    Bandits,
    Elves
}

int numFactions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Factions)).GetUpperBound(0);
float[,] repTable = new float[numFactions, numFactions];

//set a value

repTable[Townsfolk, Townsfolk] = 1.0f;
repTable[Townsfolk, Bandits] = 0.1f;
//etc.

//get a value

float rep = repTable[Townsfolk, Bandits];
```

Or if you want more information than just a single value, you can also make a 2D array of struct:

```
struct FactionStatus
{
    public float rep;
    public float affinity;
    public int debtsOwed;
}

FactionStatus[,] factionStatusTable = new FactionStatus[numFactions, numFactions];

//set a value

factionStatusTable[Bandits, Elves].affinity = 0.65f;
```